# dynamic query with date data type in spel using spring data

Tags: spring, spring-data, spring-data-jpa, spring-el

I'm struggling in creating a dynamic query with null check on date in spel using spring data. My query is:

```
 @Query(nativeQuery = true, value = "select a.* from TABLE a where"
        + "(:#{#DateFrom} is null or a.F_DATE >= trunc(:#{#DateFrom}))")
List<Acc> getAccList(@Param("DateFrom") @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE) Date datefrom);
```

> When I run this query with valid date it works, but when I pass null date I get following error:

org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessResourceUsageException: could not extract ResultSet; SQL [n/a]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not extract ResultSet

> Stack trace:

```
Caused by: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected NUMBER got BINARY

at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:439)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:395)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.processError(T4C8Oall.java:802)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.receive(T4CTTIfun.java:436)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.doRPC(T4CTTIfun.java:186)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.doOALL(T4C8Oall.java:521)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.doOall8(T4CPreparedStatement.java:205)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.executeForDescribe(T4CPreparedStatement.java:861)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.executeMaybeDescribe(OracleStatement.java:1145)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.doExecuteWithTimeout(OracleStatement.java:1267)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.executeInternal(OraclePreparedStatement.java:3449)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.executeQuery(OraclePreparedStatement.java:3493)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatementWrapper.executeQuery(OraclePreparedStatementWrapper.java:1491)
at com.ing.cbp.commons.util.logging.sql.LogablePreparedStatement.executeQuery(LogablePreparedStatement.java:77)
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.extract(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:79)
... 78 common frames omitted
```

Answer (score 1):

You need add one whitespace after 'where' keyword.

```
@Query(nativeQuery = true, value = "select a.* from TABLE a where "
    + "(:#{#DateFrom} is null or a.F_DATE >= trunc(:#{#DateFrom}))")
List<Acc> getAccList(@Param("DateFrom") @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE) Date datefrom);
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems oracle considers the `NULL` value a binary and than fails when it tries to perform `trunc` on it. [Casting it to a Date](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions016.htm) should help. So the resulting query should look like this:

```
select a.* from TABLE a where (:#{#DateFrom} is null 
or a.F_DATE >= trunc(CAST(:#{#DateFrom} AS DATE))
```

Comment: Tried it, got same exception :(

Comment: Can you remove one part of the condition at a time in order to determine which one is causing the problem? Also please log the SQL statement that actually gets executed. Finally, can you execute the SQL statement with an actual `null` literal instead of the bind variable?